# Reduce does not start, After map completes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Below is the code for my Implementation of a simple MapReduce Job using a custom writable comparable.

```
public class MapReduceKMeans {

public static class MapReduceKMeansMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, SongDataPoint, Text> {
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String str = value.toString();
        // Reading Line one by one from the input CSV.
        String split[] = str.split(",");

        String trackId = split[0];
        String title = split[1];
        String artistName = split[2];
        SongDataPoint songDataPoint = 
                new SongDataPoint(new Text(trackId), new Text(title), 
                        new Text(artistName));
        context.write(songDataPoint, new Text());
        }
    }


public static class MapReduceKMeansReducer extends
Reducer<SongDataPoint, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
    public void reduce(SongDataPoint key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(key.getTrackId()).append("\t").
        append(key.getTitle()).append("\t")
        .append(key.getArtistName()).append("\t");

        String write = sb.toString();

        context.write(new Text(write), NullWritable.get());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
            .getRemainingArgs();

    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err
                .println("Usage:<CsV Out Path> <Final Out Path>");
        System.exit(2);
    }



    Job job = new Job(conf, "Song Data Trial");
    job.setJarByClass(MapReduceKMeans.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapReduceKMeansMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MapReduceKMeansReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(SongDataPoint.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

When I debug my code reads all the rows in the CSV file but it does not enter the reduce job at all.

I also have made use of the SongDataPoint as my custom writable.

Its code is as below.

```
public class SongDataPoint implements WritableComparable<SongDataPoint> {

Text trackId;
Text title;
Text artistName;

public SongDataPoint() {
    this.trackId = new Text();
    this.title = new Text();
    this.artistName = new Text();
}

public SongDataPoint(Text trackId, Text title, Text artistName) {
    this.trackId = trackId;
    this.title = title;
    this.artistName = artistName;
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    this.trackId.readFields(in);
    this.title.readFields(in);
    this.artistName.readFields(in);
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

}

public Text getTrackId() {
    return trackId;
}

public void setTrackId(Text trackId) {
    this.trackId = trackId;
}

public Text getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(Text title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Text getArtistName() {
    return artistName;
}

public void setArtistName(Text artistName) {
    this.artistName = artistName;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(SongDataPoint o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int compare = getTrackId().compareTo(o.getTrackId());
    return compare;
}

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your output key class class as per Driver is SongDataPoint.class and output value class as Text.class but actually you are writing Text as key in Reducer and Nullwritable as value in Reducer.

Answer (score 0):

you should also specify the Mapper output values as following.

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(SongDataPoint.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

My write method in my CustomWritable Class was left blank by mistake. It solved the problem after writing the proper code in it.

```
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

}
```